# How to increase the delay that is taken to start an application when an icon is clicked in the ubuntu launcher?

Tags: 12.04, launcher

My problem is that It regularly happens that I click on the wrong icon into the ubuntu launcher and then an application is started that I don't want. Is there a way to increase the time that I have to click on an icon to start an application using the unity launcher ? Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits

Comment: Interesting question, I don't think that there is already a small delay, though, it just accepts you mouse clicks...

Comment: Take mouse cursor on the icon, and wait a while, the icon backgound will bright, you can identify using it. Or use dash, press `super` key and type the application name.